# Access network file share from azure app service - web app - ASE in hybrid setup

Tags: azure, fileshare, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-vpn, hybrid-cloud

There is an azure web app in azure app service ASE. It is linked to a Vnet. And a point to site VPN between laptops/PCs connecting to the Vnet from outside cloud/ on premises to form an hybrid cloud setup of sorts. I am trying  to see if a network file share / share folder in a PC/VM in that Vnet can be accessed from the web app (app service) . When I try this I get a **unauthorized** exception. 
what are the options do I have ?
will having a cloud service web role instead of the web app help?
Or set up a domain controller + AD in the Vnet and add VMs to the domain and trying to access the share as a domain user( impersonation via code) ?
Also I am not sure if I connect my laptop/PC to this Vnet via point to site VPN , the laptop/PC will come under the domain that we created.

The use case behind this to show some on premises media( images, videos etc possibly bigger sizes ) on a web app running in azure PaaS.

Please share your thoughts and comments.

Comment: Currently you cannot connect Azure file shares from Azure App service (web app)  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s

Comment: this is not azure file share. this is a shared folder/location in a VM inside a vnet.

Comment: @Aravind - Were you able to access you shared folder on VM through the app service? If yes, can you share what you did?